# Restart python program, reseting all lists and variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, restart

I'd like to restart my fairly large python program. So far, the way I've tried to achieve this is by doing the following:

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyFunction1() 
        os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)
```

My code is divided into many different functions, all I really want to do is allow the user to restart the program.

Using the above code causes an error second time round, when running.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, even if they simply suggest an alternative. Although, with my large code, I'm not sure a while loop might do :)

Comment: _What_ error occurs? What is expected behavior? You should create [MCVE].

Comment: sometimes, to "restart" a simple python program that doesn't have a lot of imports I've had success using the [reload()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) function, of course it has many caveats, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload)